# Перехват вывода команды в shell (bash)

Tags: скрипт, shell, bash, linux

Необходимо перехватить вывод команды в переменную для дальнейшей её обработки. Много чего перекопал, но результата пока нет.

Мой скрипт:

```
# куда закачать
output="download" 
# откуда качать
input="http://www.gym-gym.ru/news/vesti_s_mistr_junivers/2012-11-13-4"

wget $input -P $output >> z

echo $z
```

Comment: тупо гугольнул: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/ это не то что вам надо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы под результатом имеете в виду stdout или stderr?

stdout в переменную:

```
z="`wget -q -O - $input`"
```

stderr в перменную:

```
z="`wget -O /dev/null $input 2>&1`"
```

Comment: А двойные апострофы зачем? Вреда от них вроде быть не должно, но зачем?

Comment: Моя личная паранойя и техника безопасности :)

$ if [ "" = `echo` ] ; then echo TEST ; fi
-bash: [: : unary operator expected
$ if [ "" = "`echo`" ] ; then echo TEST ; fi
TEST

Comment: то что доктор прописал